# Element id/class names missing in firefox developer tools

Tags: firefox, element, inspect

Using Defeault Firefox Developer Tools in Firefox 48.0.2, when I right click an element and press Q to inspect it, I no longer see the element dom tree heirarchy/id/class names beneath the inspector toolbar. This started when I upgraded t 48.0.2. I recently upgraded to Win 10 Pro.
If I do ctrl-shift-c, I get dom tree via Firebug's inspect tool. 
I've looked all over to see what setting might toggle the element names back on using (Q) in Firefox Dev Tools. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you misspelled something. If not try using Chrome or going to the main page and checking for an update.